# Android Studio: Variable 'requiredPermissions' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working with run time permissions and trying to make a method displaying permission rationale/s for taken permission/s and rationale/s
The problem is:
"Variable 'requiredPermissions' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

That's how I call the method:

```
       showRationale(R.string.permission_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_rationale, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION});
```

And that's the method:

```
private void showRationale(int rationale, String[] requiredPermissions) {
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(R.string.go_grant_permission, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                                                                     // 'requiredPermissions' below causes the problem
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, requiredPermissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Add `final` before `String[] requiredPermissions`: `final String[] requiredPermissions`.

Answer (score 0):

You can realize onClick via interface, and not make this variable final.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
private void showRationale(int rationale, final String[] requiredPermissions) {
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout), rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(R.string.go_grant_permission, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                                                                     // 'requiredPermissions' below causes the problem
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, requiredPermissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that local variables (and method arguments) must be `final` to be accessed inside inner classes like your `OnClickListener`. So you should add a `final` keyword before a declaration of the argument. To do so, change this line

```
private void showRationale(int rationale, String[] requiredPermissions) {
```

to

```
private void showRationale(int rationale, final String[] requiredPermissions) {
```

Read more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class).